# JavaScript assignment and conditional on one line

Tags: javascript

I'm following some code in a HTML5 games book and can't understand how this line of code manages to work -

```
mp3Support = "" != audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg');
```

I've worked out it means the same as -

```
if(audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg') !=  "") {
    mp3Support = audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg');
}
```

But I can't seem to wrap my head around how it's valid. How can you assign the `mp3Support` variable to an empty string, then test to see if it's not equal to something all on the same line? I've never come across this before and it's puzzling me.

Comment: It might help you to read if you use `mp3Support = ("" != audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg'));`

Comment: And by the way, your two examples aren't the same. The first sets `mp3Support` as true/false, while your second sets `mp3Support` as "maybe" or "probably". I'd use `var mp3Support = !!audio.canPlayType("audio/mpeg");`, which sets `mp3Support` as true/false based on `audio.canPlayType("audio/mpeg")` **not** being an empty string.

Comment: Thanks to all answers, I get it now and see the difference between the two code blocks,  Cheers peeps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mp3Support` ends up being either true or false, as `x != y` returns true or false.

Same effect but shorter than writing

```
if(audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg') !=  "") mp3Support = true;
else mp3Support = false;
```

Comment: If you're referring to my deleted comment, I mis-read the OP. To me, I wouldn't use that code in the first place - I'd think you want the result of `audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg')`, not just if it's not equal to `""`. Anyways, my bad

Comment: @Bergi I would think the code **should** want the latter operand. But that's not up to me or the OP. I was just looking too much into the meaning and not what the code actually is.

Comment: Also, I don't know why, but I expected `canPlayType` to return true/false (even though the OP is comparing to `""`), but it returns "probably" or "maybe" (meaning "yes"), or "" (meaning "no"). So the code in the OP fixes what I was worrying about in the first place :)

Answer (score 0):

`mp3Support = "" != audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg');`

can be written as

`mp3Support = ("" != audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg'));`

And that last part returns either true or false.

Answer (score 0):

The `!=` operator is not an assignment operator, it is a [comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators). So on the right-hand side of the `=` (which is always executed before the `=` operator assigns a value), the code is comparing `audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg')`'s return value with an empty string. If the return value is the empty string (or any other falsey value, but you should read the comparison operator link above for details on that), then the right-hand side of the `=` statement evaluates to `false`. Otherwise the right-hand side will evaluate to `true`. The boolean value resulting from that comparison is then assigned to `mp3Support`.